# Number of black pixels with no black pixel as right neighbour

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find the number of black pixels with NO black pixel neighbours at any of right, upper right, lower right .

```
mask1 = [0|1 0|1 0; 0|1 0|1 0; 0|1 0|1 0];
black = double (x28462847_1_1 < 128);
result = conv2 (black, mask1, 'same');
count = sum (result(:) == 1)
```

I tried using this mask. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong

Comment: Why are you not sure if correct? do you define as black something smaller than 128 or is black=0?

Comment: @AnderBiguri it's giving the wrong result

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], i.e. define an example for `x28462847_1_1`.

Comment: @m7913d it's just a simple binary image

Comment: @user8751608 Just include one to make it clear or construct a (random) example on the fly. Including the expected result will make the question clear to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect all black pixels (ones) which has no black pixels at any of its 3 (upper/lower) right pixels, you can calculate the cross correlation with the following mask:

```
mask = [0  0  -1; 
        0  1  -1; 
        0  0  -1];
```

The result will be `1` for the desired positions and smaller for the others.

```
result = conv2 (double(black), rot90(mask,2), 'same') == 1; % Note that I used `conv2` with `rot90` to calculate the cross correlation. 
count = sum (result(:)); % count the number of desired elements
```

**Example**

For the following image

```
rng('default')
black = rand(10) > 0.8;
```

I obtain the following result:

```
figure
imshow(~black, 'InitialMagnification','fit')
hold on
[x, y] = find(result);
plot(y, x, '*') % highlight the found positions with an asterisk
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. From your answer above I've been able to work out how to change the masks depending on different neighbours. Taking it further, would you know how to count the number of black pixels which satisfy one rule OR another rule?

Comment: You can use `find(result1 | result2)`, which will perform an elementwise logical or.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing this is:

```
notblack=black>0; %if its not zero, then its not black

mask=[0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]% or mask=[0 0 1; 0 0 1; 0 0 1]; in your case.

result = conv2(double(notblack),mask, 'same'); % sum all values


count=sum(result(:)==sum(mask(:)));
```

Comment: What does thisones mean? And why did you use that mask?

Comment: @user8751608 typo. If you understand convolution, youll notice that that mask will add up the values that have "1". So if the answer is 4 in a pixel, it measn that those neighbours of the pixels are a "1". The mask is an example, sorry, you can modify the mask to select which pixels are important to you